# Adding a list from one class to another class in a MVC 4 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

after trying for a while to fix this, I realized since I am new to MVC 4 I just cant get this to work. I am trying to add a list of options from a Option class into another class ( it is in the model) but in a controller know since they are both part of the same view from that controller. However, I can't get the logic to work in the controller .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PollingWebsite.Models
{
public class Poll // this is a poll object with different attributes , this is a model , a class , a object
{


    public Poll()
    {
        Options1=new List<Option>();// options created into an empty list


    }


    public Poll(DateTime date, DateTime edate, int id, string question,List <Option> options1) // create an instance and giving it to me to save 
    {

        Date = date;
        Edate = edate;
        ID = id;
        Question = question;
        Options1 = options1; 

    }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date{get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Edate")]
    public DateTime Edate{get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public string Question{ get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Options1")]
    public List<Option> Options1 { get; set; }

}


public class Option// this is where the options are defined for the poll, this is the option Class
{
    public Option(int pollid, string text,int optionid) // options are a class of its own 
    {
        Pollid = pollid;
        Text = text;
        Optionid = optionid;
    }

    public Option()
    {
    //    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
    public int Pollid { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Optionid { get; set; }
}
```

Now here are my controllers in which I cant get it to work , the Create Poll control is where as you can see I want to add a Options List everytime a Poll object is read from the controller, if needed I can post my view but as of now I dont know how to add the List of options in this controller.

```
namespace PollingWebsite.Controllers
{
public class PollController : Controller // poll of poll/create
{

    //
    // GET: /Poll/Create

    public ActionResult Create() // crate a new poll 
    {
        Poll model1= new Poll();// instantiate class into instance of it
        model1.Options1.Add(new Option());// never got created options1
        model1.Options1.Add(new Option());
        return View(model1);
   }

    //
    // POST: /Poll/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Poll collection) // resolve add poll into here, in memory but 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //try
            //{
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                //var poll = PollDataSource.Instance().Get(collection.ID); // how will I call the database now?, just creating
                //if (poll != null)
                //{
                //    ModelState.AddModelError("Poll already exists", "That Poll has already been created");
                //}
                //else
                {
                     Poll numberid= PollDataSource.Instance().Add(collection.Date, collection.Edate,collection.ID, collection.Question); //calling code that calls the source that calls the database

                    foreach (Poll model in numberid)
                    {
                        PollDataSource.Instance().Add(collection.ID,collection.Options1); 
                    }

                    // get questions somehow foreach (var value in numberid)
                     //{
                       //  PollDataSource.
                     //}

                    // Authentication.Login(model.Username, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //    return View();
            //}
        }
        return View(collection);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you are not passing it data:``Option(int pollid, string text,int optionid)``

Comment: The data is being pass from the Poll Model, it has a list of options in there , which is then supposed to pass data to the option model. The problem is I cannot get the data to accept it in the controller.

Comment: but it is empty where are you adding items

Comment: _"I can't get the logic to work ..."_  - post error messages and/or describe what does (not) happen.

Comment: How ? Can you point out where exactly? I am really lost with mvc but I don't see how it is empty.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad is right. Use the other constructor whith parameters...

Comment: I am using the constructor with parameters , i dont see which line you guys are referring too , I have 2 contructors , one with parameters one without, I am trying to use the one with parameters. I need both so I am confused what you guys mean.

Comment: ``model1.Options1.Add(new Option());`` you are passing an empty option

Comment: ``model1.Options1.Add(new Option(1,"Test",1));`` now an item is added with values in it

Comment: Yeah I tried that and I still cannot access the values for the list Option in the controller.